# Put <i> inside <li> at the bottom autoresize height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style a little bit my menu.
I am using `bootstrap` and `font awesome` css styles. 
I think it will much better to show the problem on live page. 
I need to achieve two goals

1. I need to put this `chevron` icon at the bottom with little margin (2-3px) 
   like this. So it should be at the bottom in any case with little margin.

[image]

2. The problem is that `< li >` items is not resized according to the content inside it. As you can see on this screenshot. It is sticked to the bottom border and if I add some margin I will get following result

[image] 
[image]

I am using following styles

```
.item-icon-container {
    margin: 2px 0 15px 0;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
.item-icon-container .expand-indicator {
    display: block;
}
.item-icon-container .badge {
    display: block;
}
```

**Here is full `HTML` code http://pastebin.com/S26C9xSU**

Please help to solve the problem.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: just set the li width to 100% and set its left/right padding and margin to 0?

Comment: Check this answer about flow of floated elements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16736434/1949132 and try padding instead (see answer below)

Comment: Padding doesn't work, the same result.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for pointing I have just added `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that all elements inside LI affected it's height we can add last element into LI with style `clear:both`

Possible solutions:

1) Use CSS with :after selector

```
.list-group-item a:after{
  content:"";
  font-size: 1px;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

2) Extra element. At the end of each li you can add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Something like:

```
<li id="cat-id-5" class="cat-parent-empty list-group-item">
    <div class="item-icon-container">
        <span class="badge">1</span>
        <i class="fa expand-indicator fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
    <a href="http://crosp.net/category/technology/" title="View all posts in Technology">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        &nbsp; Technology
    </a>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</li>
```

CSS style looks better. Extra element has better compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this works, but putting extrad `div` into hierarchy is not good considering performance. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can try to do something with this css: 
<code>
.list-group-item a:after{ 
  content:"";
  font-size: 1px;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
</code>

Comment: that works , thanks, edit your answer please, I think this will be useful for others

Comment: Can you explain please why my code doesn't work and putting extra div solved the problem ? This is because of flow ?

Comment: Layout contains elements with `float` attribute (here it's 'float: right;'). This elements can't affect size of container, but they can push another element that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to your expand-indicator element (I'm guessing, without seeing your HTML).  https://jsfiddle.net/ve39a1qj/

```
.item-icon-container .expand-indicator {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You have provided example with the same problem I've described, grey div  is out of bounds of container, I need the parent container in my case `< li>  to be resized according content